# Why am getting error from SONAR even after removing @override Annotation.?

Tags: java, inheritance, sonarqube

```
Class A extends B{    
    protected void executeImpl(){
        super.executeImpl();
    }
}
```

Above class in being Injected in third class

```
Class C{

    A a;

    public void execute(){
    a.executeImpl()

    }

    }
```

ERROR: Description  Assignee    Resource    New issue
Useless Overriding Method : Overriding method merely calls super

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why

Comment: The error says why pretty clearly:
"Overriding method merely calls super " 
You don't add any new logic in the overriden method so there is no need to have it there.

Comment: Hi Karthik, As mentioned it is something which SONARQube is showing... if i put or don't put error remains same.

Answer (score 1):

The `@Override` annotation can only be added on inherited method. This does not mean that if you remove the annotation the method is not inherited anymore. It is still inherited !  And therefore the rule is still valid as it did not change the semantic of your program to remove the annoation.

Comment: Shall i remove  super.executeImpl();

Comment: What the rule is suggesting to you is that having this method is probably useless as having no code at all would have the same behaviour.

Comment: No, you shall remove the whole method, since it doesn't do anything that wouldn't happen anyway even without explicitly having this overriding method.

Comment: of course not, you should remove the whole method as this implementation with the call to super.executeImpl() (which I encourage you to have a closer look at what this exactly means) is exactly the same as if you have no method in this case.